# How to minify nv.d3.js?

Tags: javascript, ubuntu, minify, nvd3.js

I am a novice in Ubuntu and web-development. I have used nvd3 to build some line graphs in one of my projects. Recently I needed to customize those line graphs, which I did by making some edits in the `nv.d3.js` file. Now I am trying to minify the file so that I can replace my existing file with this new one on the SVN.

Can anyone help me with it? I read the [documentation](https://github.com/novus/nvd3) provided and read about grunt and make file/uglifyjs but it's proving to be a little too advanced for me, no doubt because of my inexperience with stuff.

Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you meant minify for use, because SVN is a little useless if you're committing minified code.

Anyhow, grab [yuicompressor](https://github.com/yui/yuicompressor/downloads), I've used it and its pretty easy.
The [usage](http://yui.github.io/yuicompressor/) is basic, all you need to do is this in a terminal;
`java -jar yuicompressor.jar -type js -o nv.d3-min.js nv.d3.js`

Thats it!

Edit:
On ubuntu, one can directly install it through
`sudo apt-get install yui-compressor`
and can use by
`yuicompressor -o <output file> <input file>`

Comment: If you're really new to *nix let me know if you need help using this terminal application. You'll need java, and for the line to work verbatim, the jar will need to be saved with the same name above, and in the same folder as the file. It'll produce a file called `nv.d3-min.js`.

Comment: thanx I tried yuicompressor and it worked perfectly without changing the behaviour of the script. Although i installed it through apt-get but thanx for suggesting it :)

Comment: no problem, let others know it works by selecting the answer as correct

Comment: added the rejected edit by @SurenderThakran because I think it's viable, esp. since a tag is 'Ubuntu'